# Regex to allow only given special characters

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I am trying to create a regex for accepting uppercase, lowercase letters, numbers and only mentioned special characters for creating password. What I have built works fine, however, when I add a special character mentioned and one which is not in the list, it is still accepted.

What I have built:

`^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%&\*])(?=.{8,})`

What happens here is that when I enter # it works. When I enter # **AND** +, it still accepts. I need it to fail and only allow characters mentioned. If the user enters one which is not mentioned, it should fail

Comment: I would advise you to simply use a managed data flow for your passwords so that you don't care what's in them.  We've come a long way since SQL injection attacks demanded non-unusual characters.  Heck, even permit unicode characters.  Nothing says you can't.

Comment: Can you specify which special characters you're looking to match on?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the regex you are looking for is

`^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%&*])[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%&*]{8,}$`

In this regex, `[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%&*]` is a character class that matches any uppercase letter, lowercase letter, digit, or one of the specified special characters. By including this character class in the main pattern and ensuring that it matches the entire password string from start to end, the regex will reject any passwords that contain special characters not explicitly mentioned.

Comment: I tried this. But it still does not work how I need it to. For example, if my password has a special character mentioned AND a special character not mentioned, I want the validation to fail. However, the moment I enter a character mentioned, the validation is accepted even though others are in the password

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%&*]+$`

The key here is the `+` at the end. It allows unlimited characters from the specified set to be included in the match.

This set will:

- Match uppercase
- Match lowercase
- Match Numbers
- Match special characters (specified between `9` and `]`)
- Match any length and any combination.

I'd maybe suggest using alternative requirements though. This is the regex I use for passwords. It requires a minimum of 8 characters, one upper, one lower, one number, and one symbol (of any kind).

`^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[^\w\s]).{8,}$`